# android game running slow on fast devices

Tags: android, performance, opengl-es

I've made a android game, having this as main game loop :

```
// desired fps
private final static int    MAX_FPS = 60;
// maximum number of frames to be skipped
private final static int    MAX_FRAME_SKIPS = 5;

// the frame period
private final static int    FRAME_PERIOD = 1000 / MAX_FPS;  
int sleepTime = 0;      // ms to sleep (<0 if we're behind)
int framesSkipped;      // number of frames being skipped 

private float   dt = 0; 



@Override
public void onDrawFrame(GL10 gl) 
{
    gl.glClear(GL10.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL10.GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT );

    dt = game.gTimer.update(false);


    doDraw(gl);
    doUpdate(20); // <<-- UPDATE (Step = 20units)

    sleepTime = (int)(FRAME_PERIOD - dt); // calculate sleep time

    if (sleepTime > 0) {    // if sleepTime > 0 we're OK
        try 
        {
            // send the thread to sleep for a short period
            // very useful for battery saving
            Thread.sleep(sleepTime);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {}
    }

    while (sleepTime < 0 && framesSkipped < MAX_FRAME_SKIPS) {
        // we need to catch up - update without rendering

        doUpdate(20);  // <<-- UPDATE (Step = 20units)

        // add frame period to check if in next frame
        sleepTime += FRAME_PERIOD;
        framesSkipped++;
    }

    gl.glFlush();
}
```

The problem is that it runs slower (~40fps !!! expected > 50) on fast device (Samsung Galaxy S3 for example) and runs faster (ranging 42 ~ 70fps) on slower devices (Samsung Galaxy mini, Allview AllDro Speed, LG Optimus One)

**UPDATE - rendering code (of a 3d object/cube) :**

```
    public void render(GL10 gl, int texID)
{
    gl.glEnableClientState(GL10.GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);
    gl.glEnableClientState(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_COORD_ARRAY);

    //Bind texture in this case
    gl.glBindTexture(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_2D, texID);

        //Enable the vertex and texture state
        gl.glVertexPointer(3, GL10.GL_FLOAT, 0, vertexBuffer[0]);
        gl.glTexCoordPointer(2, GL10.GL_FLOAT, 0, textureBuffer[0]);

        //Draw the vertices as triangles, based on the Index Buffer information
        gl.glDrawElements(GL10.GL_TRIANGLES, indexBuffer[0].capacity(), GL10.GL_UNSIGNED_SHORT, indexBuffer[0]);

    gl.glDisableClientState(GL10.GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);
    gl.glDisableClientState(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_COORD_ARRAY);
}
```

I'm loading only one 3d object in memory. (wich is rendered 10 times in doDraw).
I have als an ArrayList<> of cubes/3d-objects for 3d position and physx tracking.

Comment: Sooooo, what does `doDraw()` actually render? that's kinda the most important info, if you want us to be able to answer why this is slow...

Comment: it renders about 10 textured cubes - in 3d. slow fps  happens on level 0 in the game, when only 10 cubes are rendered.  on higher levels cube count is highere (from 15 ~ 40). but the problem is that even on level 0 the fps is ~ 40 fps on samsung s3. :( just dont have any ideea why. it's constant at ~ 40fps. on other and slower devices it works faster > 40fps.

Comment: Don't just say "it renders about 10 textured cubes", the reaaally important part, is HOW do you RENDER THEM?

Comment: i've updated above drawing my 3d objects. Should i try removing the doUpdate/doDraw methods and see if still getting the 40 fps ? have you experienced similar behavior ? is my game loop implemented ok ?

Comment: And I repeat, post the `doDraw()` method, that's the one you're actually calling.

Comment: here you are (too big to fit here) http://pastebin.com/FJij7rWq     thanks.

Comment: It looks like you're using a BUNCH of old, deprecated and slow functions. Like `glPushMatrix()`, `glTranslatef()`, `glRotatef()`, `glMatrixMode()`, etc. That could be the cause, since well as said they are old, deprecated and slow.

Comment: I dont think that that's the problem. OpenglES methods shoud be fast enough and have a good internal implementation wich must run fast enough. Anyways, this does not explay why on fast hardware it has low FPS when it shoud be processed faster comparing to slow devices. I will do some tests with drawing just a simple square and see what happens (also my game loop will remain unchanged) and also must find some more devices to test on.  I must thank you for your time !!

Comment: Those functions are slow, you're suppose to handle those matrix calculations yourself and use Shaders. Also my next guess without looking too much at your code would be the `Thread.sleep()` and how you calculate the `sleepTime` guessing that you doesn't calculate the `sleepTime` correctly. Also don't use `Thread.sleep()` at all.

Comment: OK, I'll check that too.  Allright, thank you very much.